# WSDL: how to describe an element with attribute and string-value at the same time?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I can describe a structure like this:

```
<element name="One" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="Two" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

It leads to:

```
<One>
  <Two>str 1</Two>
  <Two>str 2</Two>
</One>
```

Also I can describe a structure like this:

```
<element name="One" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="Two" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <complexType>
          <attribute name="MyAttr" type="string" />
        </complexType>
      </element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

It leads to:

```
<One>
  <Two MyAttr="str 1" />
  <Two MyAttr="str 2" />
</One>
```

But how to describe a structure which leads to something like this:

```
<One>
  <Two MyAttr="str 1">str 2</Two>
  <Two MyAttr="str 3">str 4</Two>
</One>
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="One">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Two" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="MyAttr" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

the output will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<One xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Two MyAttr="String">String</Two>
    <Two MyAttr="String">String</Two>
</One>
```